# Why event.target.value is truncated?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I set some data in HTML element as value. But when I get value by using `e.target.value`, it truncates the value.

```
  <li value="74fd5135-e756-41af-a0f7-6eaf20bc2551" OnClick= 
  {this.SelectedItem}>Something </li>

  SelectedItem =(e)=>
  {
   e.target.value ;   //its gives me 74
  }
```

It should return me the same data as I set which is

74fd5135-e756-41af-a0f7-6eaf20bc2551

Comment: _"`value`: This **integer attribute** indicates the current ordinal value of the list item as defined by the <ol> element. **The only allowed value for this attribute is a number**, even if the list is displayed with Roman numerals or letters."_ ([Source](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/li))

Comment: not the same as [input](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input#value) value

Comment: Just use `data-value` instead of `value`, since you clearly don't want that content to have the intended effect of the `value` attribute.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can pass like this.

```
 //option 1
 <li OnClick={()=>this.SelectedItem("74fd5135-e756-41af-a0f7-6eaf20bc2551")}>Something </li>

 //option 2
 <li OnClick={this.SelectedItem.bind(this,"74fd5135-e756-41af-a0f7-6eaf20bc2551"}>Something </li>

  SelectedItem =(value)=>
  {
    console.log(value);
  }
```

Answer (score 4):

The `value` attribute of a list item can only contain numbers

> `value`
>
> This **integer attribute** indicates the current ordinal value of the list item as defined by the  element. **The only allowed value for this attribute is a number**, even if the list is displayed with Roman numerals or letters. List items that follow this one continue numbering from the value set. The value attribute has no meaning for unordered lists (`<ul>`) or for menus (`<menu>`).

Source: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/li

The definition of the `value` attribute for a list item:

```
[Exposed=Window, HTMLConstructor]
interface HTMLLIElement : HTMLElement {
  [CEReactions] attribute long value;
};
```

Source: https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/dom.html#concept-element-dom